# Comparar una variable que cambia a lo largo de tiempo con un valor anterior al actual (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Tengo una pregunta sencilla sobre Javascript.

Tengo que hacer un sencillo programa que recoge un valor. 
Este valor lo almaceno en una variable.
Tengo otra variable donde se van almacenando todos los valores que van apareciendo.

Tengo que hacer un programa que recoja el valor en una variable en un instante determinado, este valor es el Pagename que se le asigna a cada página web. Este valor va cambiando a lo largo de la navegación de un usuario.

El caso es que quiero almacenar el pagename (eso lo se hacer) pero necesito comparar si el valor del Pagename a lo largo de la navegación ha cambiado, es decir, comparar el pagename actual en el que nos encontramos con el anterior.
Que después almacene en una variable tipo array todos los valores.

Me gustaría que alguien me ayudase con la lógica, estoy un poco atascado.

Estoy preparando el programa con tres variables:

Pagename
PagenameActual
PagenameAnterior

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow, porfavor leete antes https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y edita tu pregunta para indicarnos en que punto estás y como podemos ayudarte ¡Gracias!

Comment: Necesito que alguien me explique la lógica...si tengo que meter un bucle...estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: No se entiende del todo lo que quieres conseguir, menos aún si no indicas nada de tu codigo. Para comparar si ya has añadido un elemento a la Array de valores usa `Array.includes()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Comment: Creo que amenos deberías compartirnos como estas almacenando tu `Pagename` para hacernos una mejor idea. También me quedan dudas si lo que estas haciendo es un `SPA` o almacenas en valor en localstorage o similar para guardar durante la navegación.

Answer (score -1):

Mi idea es que almacenes las páginas que vas visitando en un array:

```
//Lista de páginas visitadas    
var paginasVisitadas=[];
//Cada vez que cambies de página
paginasVisitadas.push(paginaActual);
//para comprobar si coincide con la última página visitada
if(paginaActual==paginasVisitadas[paginasVisitadas.length-1])
{
//hacer algo cuando es la mísma página
}
else
{
//hacer algo cuando no
}
```